# Django not creating other field, only the date field is created

Tags: django, model

**I have a model but its not creating the other fields except for datefield whenever i do makemigrations**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()

class User(models.Model):
    user_fname = models.CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length=200),
    user_lname = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last Name', max_length=200),
    user_email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Email'),
    user_position = models.CharField(verbose_name='Position', max_length=200),
    pub_date = models.DateField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_email
```

Comment: import datetime
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.utils.timezone import utc


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='pub_date',
            field=models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 27, 1, 33, 56, 928545, tzinfo=utc)),
        ),
    ]

Answer (score 0):

Because all other fields have comma at the end. remove the commas:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_fname = models.CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length=200)
    user_lname = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last Name', max_length=200)
    user_email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Email')
    user_position = models.CharField(verbose_name='Position', max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_email
```

make migrations again:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate
```